# Create SSLSocket by SSLSocketFactory with set connection timeout

Tags: java, android, sockets, timeout

My code is here:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, getAllCerts(), new SecureRandom());
SSLSocketFactory factory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
mSocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("myhost.com", socketPort[index]);
```

I have to check table of ports and choose the open one. Everything works ok, but on createSocket() my application loose a lot of time. If I have 5 ports and the last is open connecting takes about 3 minutes.

How can I set timeout on SSLSocketFactory to speed up connection?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you expect to speed up the process of connecting by setting a timeout. Where does your code run? In an AsyncTask? In a Service? Any initial data transfers? Did you consider a SSLSessionCache?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same problem, and it would be great if you can post your solution... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

In case you are still wondering, you can use the idea given in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/EYtMO5WoXXI

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

// Create a socket without connecting
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
Socket socket = socketFactory.createSocket();

// Connect, with an explicit timeout value
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(endpoint.mServer,
endpoint.mPort), CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
```

Comment: This did the trick for me! Didn't think about the possibility to create a socket without a connection.

Comment: Doesn't work with SSL because `java.net.SocketException: Unconnected sockets not implemented`

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping an existing socket instead:

```
Socket socketConn = new Socket();
socketConn.connect(addr, DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
mSocket = socketConn.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socketConn, hostname, port, true);
```

Comment: Did you test this? I would expect the createSocket() method in your last line to close the socket first, because it is already in a connected (non-SSL) state. Also, according to the docs, SSL Socket Factories with a specified SSL handshake timeout reset the underlying's socket timeout to 0 (aka no timeout) after the SSL protocol is finished establishing the connection.

Comment: @ClassStacker You are mistaken. I've done this. It works. (1) This is how you implement the STARTTLS command of SMTP, LSAP, etc, so you will find the same thing inside JavaMail, the JNDI LDAP provider, etc. (2) This is a connect timeout, not a read timeout, which is what your final sentence is about. (3) Please cite a reference for that claim. The word 'timeout' does not appear in the Javadoc for SSLSocketFactory *or* SSLSocket, except in the latter case as a reference to the methods inherited from Socket.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case because I needed to ensure that the socket was bind to a certain network. With `new Socket()` the socket will still be bind to the default network.

Comment: @winklerrr That's not correct. The new socket isn't bound at all until you connect it, and it is then bound to the correct network for the connection, as determined by the IP routing to the target.

Comment: @EJP you said to the "correct network by IP routing" - but that doesn't work in my case. How can I contact you?

Comment: @winklerrr You *are* contacting me. If you need to bind the socket, bind it, before connecting it.

Comment: @EJP check my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46243435/force-webview-to-operate-on-a-certain-network) for more information about my problem. In my case it's not bound to the correct network.